# Creating a new function based off exisiting one

Tags: evil, advice

I apologize if this is a duplicate, but the essence of the question is whether it is possible to create "around" advice for an existing function and bind that to a new one.

In my case, I'm trying to change how `evil-delete` and similar functions handle the kill ring, namely by inserting into the second position instead of the first. I already have a function that accomplishes this, called `yf-kill-new-second-pos`, however I cannot figure out how to cleanly define a derivative of `evil-delete` that uses this instead of `kill-new` without either copying and pasting or (I admit I haven't tried this) advising `evil-delete`, which would undesirably change it's functionality.

I attempted to solve the issue by using `symbol-function` to grab the source for `evil-delete` and then wrapping that in an `flet` to redefine `kill-new`, but that did nothing to change the function's behavior (even when set to nil). Code:

```
(evil-define-operator yf-d (beg end type register yank-handler)
  "Evil-delete that dumps to 2nd in kill ring by default"
  ;;Same interactive clause as evil-delete
  (interactive "<R><x><y>")
  (cl-flet ((kill-new #'yf-kill-new-second-pos))
    (funcall (symbol-function 'evil-delete) beg end type register)))

;;testing measure 
(bind-key (kbd "<f7>") 'yf-d)
```

This may not be changing anything because `evil-delete` is byte-compiled, but I'm not entirely sure. It could also have something to do with evil-define-operator, but again, I don't know how to test around this. Any help in solving this issue would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You ask "*whether it is possible to create "around" advice for an existing function and bind that to a new one*". Yes. Did you try it? an "around" advice lets you completely replace the behavior of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I attempted to solve the issue by ... wrapping that in an `flet` to redefine kill-new ...

Except you actually used `cl-flet` which is quite different.

```el
(cl-flet ((kill-new #'yf-kill-new-second-pos))
  (evil-delete beg end type register))
```

`cl-flet` creates a local function definition which is visible only (and non-recursively) to its body code.  Functions called *by* that body code do not see it.  As `kill-new` is not called directly by the body code, this usage of `cl-flet` has no practical effect.

`flet`, OTOH, creates function overrides which are visible for the entire scope of the form, so if that call to `evil-delete` ultimately causes `kill-new` to be called, it would be your function which was called.

```el
(flet ((kill-new (string &optional replace)
                 (yf-kill-new-second-pos string replace)))
  (evil-delete beg end type register))
```

These days `flet` is marked as deprecated, but there's an analogous way to do the same thing with `cl-letf`:

```el
(cl-letf (((symbol-function 'kill-new) #'yf-kill-new-second-pos))
  (evil-delete beg end type register))
```

---

Now I don't know how you've defined `yf-kill-new-second-pos`, but obviously you don't want a dynamic binding for `kill-new` which *calls* `kill-new`, so you might consider advising `kill-new` itself:

```el
(defvar my-kill-2nd)

(defadvice kill-new (around my-kill-new-2nd)
  "If `my-kill-2nd' is non-nil, kills go to the second position of the `kill-ring'."
  (if (and kill-ring (bound-and-true-p my-kill-2nd))
      (let ((real-kill-ring kill-ring)
            (kill-ring (cdr kill-ring)))
        ad-do-it
        (setcdr real-kill-ring kill-ring))
    ad-do-it))

(ad-activate 'kill-new)

(let ((my-kill-2nd t))
  (evil-delete beg end type register))
```

Comment: Thank you sou much! I wasn't aware of how precisely `cl-flet` worked, nor `cl-letf`. Here is the code of my function for future reference. https://pastebin.com/s254NQSZ